# AngularJS page takes long to load

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot

I'm creating a page using AngularJS as front-end and SpringBoot as back-end. I'm completely new to AngularJS and I can't figure out why it takes so long for my page to load.

Thank's for any help in advance.

This is the link to my page:

Comment: I wouldn't expect users to click on a link, especially one that suspicious. Please post relevant code in your question. For more info review [ask]

Comment: Ok, but i don't know what i can show.

Comment: I already opened your site with the chrome console, and it loads in less than 3 seconds. Please make sure that your internet connection is ok, your PC doesn't have any process consuming your CPU and put some relevant code in your question to help you better.

Comment: I don't know why you have the tag xpages listed.  It doesn't sound like you're using XPages technology here at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the modern JavaScript frameworks come with a learning curve you have to get over. For AngularJS, since you are new to it, I would strongly suggest you use AngularJS2. It's faster than 1.x. 
Familiarise yourself with the build process - in production environment you want all your files packed and minified. 
For a general approach have a look at [this blog article](http://www.notessensei.com/blog/2015/10/domino-grunt-json-and-yeoman.html) (a little older, but you get the gist).

For Angular2 check out the [Angular Seed project](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed)

Watching some tutorials on YouTube about the build process will help too